# How to get row index when column equals 1 in R dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to get row numbers in list when dataframe columns equals 1. Example code:

```
emp.data <- data.frame(
   emp_name = c("Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary"),
   salary = c(623.3,515.2,611.0,729.0,843.25),
   start_date = as.Date(c("2012-01-01", "2013-09-23", "2014-11-15", "2014-05-11",
      "2015-03-27")),
    column = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1),
   stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
emp.data <- tail(emp.data, 3)
emp.data
```

I tried this:

```
result <-as.numeric(rownames(emp.data[emp.data$column==1,]))
```

but i get this output:

```
4 5
```

and i need output like this:

```
2 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `which` on a logical expression instead of `row.names` as `row.names` can be different

```
which(emp.data$column == 1)
```

Comment: damn you were faster :-)) Wanted to post exactly this :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can reset rownames:

```
#Code
rownames(emp.data)<-NULL
result <-as.numeric(rownames(emp.data[emp.data$column==1,]))
```

The fastest and most optimal way would be (many thanks and credits to **@RuiBarradas**):

```
#Code2
rownames(emp.data)<-NULL
result <- rownames(emp.data)[emp.data$column == 1]
```

Comment: Note that `rownames(emp.data)[emp.data$column == 1]` is way more efficient. It gets the rownames based on `emp.data$column==1`, like in the questions' code but then subsets a much simpler data structure, a vector.

Comment: @RuiBarradas It is a great suggestion. I will add that to the post with credits to you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try `seq_along` like below

```
> with(emp.data, seq_along(column)[column == 1])
[1] 2 3
```